# Rails 6. Render a js.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to render a js.erb view inside a Model's method:

```
ApplicationController.render(template: 'js/library.js.erb', assigns: {foo: 'bar'},  handlers: [:js], formats: [:js])
```

works perfect, but I'm also getting:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rendering actions with '.' in the name is deprecated:
```

But then if I try:

```
 ApplicationController.render(template: 'js/library', assigns: {foo: 'bar'},  handlers: [:js], formats: [:js])
```

I'm getting:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate
Missing template js/library.js with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:js]}.
```

so, what is the correct way to render a **js.erb** file on Rails 6?

Comment: `I need to render a js.erb view inside a Model's method`... why !? This breaks MVC, SRP and a lot more.

Comment: Shouldn't the handler be `:erb` instead of `:js`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Call a specific Controller's action, id est, a controller that already exists:

```
JsController.render('js/library', assigns: assigns)
```